# Video file not trimming and copying using FFMpeg in C#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, video-editing

I am trying to clip a video using C# in Visual Studios with FFMpeg. I run the code below and it doesn't come back with any errors, except it doesn't create a new video file.

I've looked around here to make sure I'm using the correct code, but after multiple attempts it still won't copy.

```cs
string videoFile = @"C:\Users\dave\Documents\video 1.mp4";
string outputFile = @"C:\Users\dave\Documents\video 2.mp4";

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\dave\Documents\ffmpeg.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "ffmpeg -i " + videoFile + " -ss 00:30:00 -t 00:00:10 -c copy " + outputFile;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.Start();
```

I was expecting to get a video cut from the original video, starting at the 30 second mark and lasting 10 seconds, but nothing is created.

I am using the latest FFMpeg from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

*UPDATE If I run the code in command prompt - The file comes out corrupt though*

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\\Users\\dave\\Documents\\video 1.mp4" -ss 00:30:00 -t 00:00:10 -c copy "C:\\Users\\dave\\Documents\\video 2.mp4"
ffmpeg version N-93851-gdcc999819d Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.3.1 (GCC) 20190414
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 27.100 / 56. 27.100
  libavcodec     58. 52.101 / 58. 52.101
  libavformat    58. 27.103 / 58. 27.103
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 51.100 /  7. 51.100
  libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\\Users\\dave\\Documents\\video 1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    creation_time   : 2019-01-15T21:57:04.000000Z
    title           : My Movie
    encoder         : Lavf56.15.102
    description     : This video is about My Movie
  Duration: 00:06:48.22, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1283 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1202 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn, 2997 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-01-15T21:57:04.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 74 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-01-15T21:57:04.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\\Users\\dave\\Documents\\video 2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    description     : This video is about My Movie
    title           : My Movie
    encoder         : Lavf58.27.103
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 1202 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn, 11988 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-01-15T21:57:04.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 74 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-01-15T21:57:04.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: Your input and output file names have spaces in them, maybe they needs to be quoted?

Comment: I've tried both '' and `` around the file location but still not working.

Comment: Do you have an example of the ffmpeg command working from the command line using those file names?

Comment: @stuartd I've updated the original post with what happens when I run the command. The file comes out corrupt though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try in this way:

```
string videoFile = @"C:\Users\dave\Documents\video 1.mp4";
string outputFile = @"C:\Users\dave\Documents\video 2.mp4";
string command = @"ffmpeg -i ""{0}"" -ss 00:30:00 -t 00:00:10 ""{1}""";
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\dave\Documents\ffmpeg.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(command,videoFile,outputFile);
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.Start();
```

Comment: This didn't work either. I think it is something wrong with the ffmpeg.exe file, but I have the latest one from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/. Could it be some kind of settings? Is there a way to catch errors with ffmpeg?

Comment: I modified the code again, debug and check the command at this point process.StartInfo.Arguments , copy the same in the command prompt where the ffmpeg exe is running and execute. You will find the second file at the same specified place if the command executed successfully.

Comment: for example: E:\>ffmpeg -i "E:\FinalTest 1.mp4" -ss 00:30:00 -t 00:00:10 -c copy "E:\FinalTest 2.mp4"

Comment: if the path in the command is without double quotes then it will not work. It should be  like "E:\FinalTest 1.mp4"

Comment: The arguement as I step in looks like this. "ffmpeg -i \"C:\\Users\\dave\\Documents\\video 1.mp4\" -ss 00:30:00 -t 00:00:10 -c copy \"C:\\Users\\dave\\Documents\\video 2.mp4\""

Comment: If you run this command ffmpeg -i \"C:\\Users\\dave\\Documents\\video 1.mp4\" -ss 00:30:00 -t 00:00:10 -c copy \"C:\\Users\\dave\\Documents\\video 2.mp4\" in command prompt then it will work. You will see the second file video 2.mp4 at the same location.

Comment: It says it is invalid, but when I remove the single \ it creates the second file but with no data.

Comment: yep no need to include single \ ,by mistake I added that in previous comment. And you are right file created with no data, for this you need to check the proper trimming/copy command. Go through the link
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

Comment: Remove -c copy from the command and check the output then, I tried the same and its working fine. 
ffmpeg -i "C:\\Users\\dave\\Documents\\video 1.mp4" -ss 00:30:00 -t 00:00:10  "C:\\Users\\dave\\Documents\\video 2.mp4"

Comment: Yes this works perfectly in the command prompt. When I do the same in C# it still has the single \.

Comment: It works in C# when I take the ffmpeg from the start.

Comment: yes, it still has the single \ in c#. The backslash ( "\" ) character is a special escape character used to indicate other special characters such as new lines (\n), tabs (\t), or quotation marks (\"). And we have used double quotes to specify the "file path".